# How to get bot command values of another Discord bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to have my bot keep track of items that are being spawned by another bot (Mee6).

The following code gives me a None output.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message:discord.Message):
    if message.author.bot:
        print(message.content)
```

The command the other bot is responding to is:

*/spawn-item member={member} item={item} amount={amount}*

I would like to retrieve these values.

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: You are getting `None` because you don't have [intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html) enabled.

Comment: @ConnerWolf08 I do have that: client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix,intents=discord.Intents.all())

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work, because you want to get an interaction, not a message.

Unfortunately, there is no way to get the interaction of another client. At most you can have a MessageInteraction, which gives you the name of the command used.

But in your case you can make it work since MEE6 still accepts the old command format. If you use the prefix of MEE6 instead of the / command, your code should work (with a bit of reworking: you would need to look at the message right before MEE6's response, or look if a message starts with the MEE6's prefix)